# Can someone tell me breifly how sharepoint works?

Tags: sharepoint

I have been trying to find a simple answer for a while now but I can't seem to get a direct answer?! Can someone please put it into simple terms? Thanks it would be much appreciated

Comment: google for a sharepoint tutorial?

Comment: This is a request for a product description, not a programming question.

Comment: It's rare to find a simple answer to such a vague and open-ended question.  Can you explain what aspect of SharePoint you want to understand?

Comment: It is written in a unique language, made entirely from "Unexpected Error" exceptions.

Comment: How SharePoint works: occasionally.

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint is a content management system (CMS) build with an ASP.NET front end, and an XML based backend running on IIS and SQL Server.

A good start is wikipedia:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint

Comment: If you read the wikipedia entry you'd see that it's a lot more than just a CMS!

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint is just a one stop shop portal.  It allows you to manage documents, provide workflow, and collaboration.  It even can be built to work like a CRM system, especially the 2010 version which is .net based.

All in all it is a good intranet tool for a company big or small.  It can handle documents and provide information like when the document was updated, what was updated, checking in / out documents.

It also allows you to post notes, reminders, notifications for company wide functional groups.  You can strict it to be departmental.  It is a monster that is based on a SQL SERVER backend with some notorious tables.  You can build lists of any sort, import Excel data, and create performance indicators for things like reports or management content.

Just a very large CMS (can be CRM) / Document Mgmt / Anything embedded from .net system.

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint is a system for shared calenders, appointments, discussions, document tracking, crm and cms solutions...

Good for internal use - but can equally be used external public face content manageable sites.